# PHP Curl Tor Pages Not Displaying

Tags: php, html, curl, tor

I have this code

```
<?php 

$ua = array(
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; AOL 9.7; AOLBuild 4343.19; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; FunWebProducts)",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X Mach-O; XH; rv:8.578.498) fr, Gecko/20121021 Camino/8.723+ (Firefox compatible)",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1",
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; fr-fr) AppleWebKit/525.1+ (KHTML, like Gecko, Safari/525.1+) midori/1.19",
"Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; Ubuntu/14.10) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; de-ch; HTC Sensation Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");

$uar = array_rand($ua);

$url = "sometestserverisetup";  
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '9051';
$auth = 'mypwwhateveritis';
$command = 'signal NEWNYM';

$fp = fsockopen($ip,$port,$error_number,$err_string,10);
if(!$fp) { echo "ERROR: $error_number : $err_string";
return false;
} else {
fwrite($fp,"AUTHENTICATE \"".$auth."\"\n");
$received = fread($fp,512);
fwrite($fp,$command."\n");
$received = fread($fp,512);
}

fclose($fp);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$ua[$uar]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
?>
```

everything works fine. With my test site and it displays correctly. However certain sites (google.com, amazon.com, youtube, facebook. only display a blank page for echo response.

Is there some curl set opt that needs to be enabled for pages to display properly.

Comment: Some more informations might help. You will get them with a call of `$latestResponse = curl_getinfo($ch);` after `$response = curl_exec($ch);`. `var_dump($latestResponse);` will print the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at a `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` after calling `curl_exec` can be helpful.

I tested your code and found in some cases the sites send a `302 Moved` response with a `Location` header to redirect the browser which would result in an empty response on a successful request.

Adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

made it so that every site you mentioned always returned a response in my tests.  And depending on what you are doing (searches, logins, form submissions) you will probably find redirects are common so you need to tell cURL to follow them with that option.

Beyond that, you can set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true` so you can look at the response headers sent to see what's going on in addition to `curl_getinfo` to make sure the connection was successful (either through Tor or to the site).